# Conditional Expectation for a RV conditioned on a sigma algebra generated by a family of sets

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Conjecture: 
Suppose the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$, where $X \in m\mathcal F$ is a Random Variable which is integrable. Let $\mathcal A \subseteq \mathcal F$, and denote $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ to be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the collection of sets $\mathcal A$. Then to verify that $\mathbb E[X; A] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[X | \sigma(\mathcal A)]; A]$  (the "orthogonality condition") for any $A \in \sigma(\mathcal A)$, it suffices to show that the afforementioned holds looking only at $A \in \mathcal A$.

I am studying probability theory, and I found myself wondering whether the above is true. I know it holds if $\mathcal A$ is a partition of $\Omega$, but does it hold in the general case as well for any family of sets? If so, does anybody have a good proof resource, link, or guidance to offer? I can't figure out how to prove it myself.

What I know is true is that if $\mathcal A$ is a countable partition where $P(A_n) > 0$ for all $A_n \in \mathcal A$, then it suffices to check only whether the orthogonality condition holds on $A_n \in \mathcal A$, rather than considering the full $\sigma(\mathcal A)$, but I can't quite work out the proof as to why, nor find a good resource. I am having trouble justifying When $A \in \sigma(\mathcal A)$ is countable. Particularly, I can express $A = \bigsqcup_{n}A_n$ as the disjoint union of elements of the partition (due to the fact that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a partition is the set containing unions of elements of the partition), and I am able to use the integrability of $X$ combined with the DCT to break $\mathbb E[X; \sqcup_n A_n]$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X; \sqcup_n A_n] &= \sum_n \mathbb E[X; A_n]
\end{align*}
But for $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X | \sigma(\mathcal A)]; A]$ I can't figure out how the DCT would apply as I don't know that it's integrable. If I were able to conclude it were integrable the conclusion is immediate.

Comment: The conjecture is false. You need some additional condition on $\mathcal A$. If it is closed under finite intersections then the result is true (by $\pi-\lambda$ theorem).

Comment: Ah; that makes sense! How about for the partition case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathcal A$ is a countable partition then $\sigma (\mathcal A)$ is nothing but the collection of all posssible unions of sets from $\mathcal A$. Hence the result is true in this case.

As pointed out in my comment above the result is not true in general.

Comment: What makes that result obvious for any $\mathcal A$ s.t. $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ is countable?

Comment: @Eric There is no countably infinite sigma algebra.

Comment: oh; sorry, I meant if $\mathcal A = \left\{A_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ was a countable partition. Suppose that $A \in \mathcal A$, so there exists $\mathcal J \subseteq \mathbb N$ s.t. $A = \bigsqcup_{j \in \mathcal J}A_j$. I end up with an integral over an integral $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X \big| \sigma(\mathcal A)] ; \bigsqcup_{j \in \mathcal J} A_j]$ and I would want to be able to express this as $\sum_{j}\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X \big|\sigma(\mathcal A)]; A_j]$ at which point I would be done.

Comment: This is easy to do for $\mathbb E[X ; \bigsqcup_{j \in \mathcal J} A_j]$ as I can invoke the integrability of $X$ to achieve the result easily; ie, $\sum_j \mathbb E[X ; A_j]$. But not so sure how to do so for $\mathbb E[X \big | \sigma(\mathcal A)]$. Does my question make sense? Or does it seem way out of line to you.

Comment: And to recap, the goal is to demonstrate the orthogonality condition (ie, $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X \big | \sigma(\mathcal A)] ; A] = \mathbb E[X; A]$ for all $A \in \sigma(\mathcal A)$). I agree it seems trivial but I'm having trouble getting that infinite sum out front at which point the result is obvious (if the sum is infinite, the integral and the sum interchanging is not immediate, is where this question roots from. It is probably just Fubini or DCT if I had to guess but I am having trouble seeing why for some reason).